# My modal dialog form not submit to the controller in php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In modal dialog form submit value are not passed in to the my controller

```
function save()
{
    var url;
    url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/User/book_update')?>";
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}
```

while submitting form button no response only Error adding / update data shows

```
            public function book_update()
            {
            $markid= $this->input->post('markid');
            $subcode=$this->input->post('subcode');
            echo $markid;
            echo $subcode;
            }
```

Comment: It does submit, but the request fails. Add `console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);` to your `error`-callback and check the console what it says. You can also check the network tab in your browsers development tools to see what the request actually returns (any errors etc from your upload controller)

Comment: show your `book_update` method also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you**

Your `url` should be like this  :

```
url = "<?php echo site_url('User/book_update')?>";
```

Instead of this :

```
url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/User/book_update')?>";
```

`js` function should be like this :

```
function save()
{
    var url;
    url = "<?php echo site_url('User/book_update')?>";
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}
```

Your controller's `book_update` method should be like this :

```
public function book_update()
{
   $markid = $this->input->post('markid');
   $subcode = $this->input->post('subcode');
   $array = array('markid' => $markid);
   echo json_encode($array);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: my button is <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> my modal is <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog" >

Comment: so what is the error u getting?, is your model is working fine ?

Comment: model file attached

Comment: updated my answer, to check for the response see the browser console tab

Comment: in console i got this error jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/Admin-Panel/User/book_update 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: go to the network tab and see what url it is showing

Comment: internal server error means your path is not correctly defined there

Comment: <script src="http://localhost/Admin-Panel/assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: show screenshot of your error not link,have you set  your base_url in your config.php

Comment: $base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;

Comment: over tried simply put this : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/AdminPanel/';`

Comment: now modal form closed. but i want to print markid and subcode values using echo or print_r not working

Comment: where do you want to print these values ,

Comment: in controller or model any thing. because based on this values i m setting as a parameter to open xlsx file that's y

Comment: i think you already getting these variable using `$markid = $this->input->post('markid');` use it in your controller for whatever u want

Comment: ajax will not show you data like the normal form submission to see the data you have to go to browser console or network tab

Comment: `echo  $this->input->post('markid');` in your controller and see the result in your browser's network tab

Comment: by the way if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to upvote and check it green